# Rails 4: Trying to use Ancestry with jstree

Tags: json, xslt, ruby-on-rails-4, jstree, ancestry

I am new to Rails and trying to populate a jstree in the browser with JSON from the Ancestry gem (see https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry). JSON is the go-between. Where I am stuck is translating the JSON produced (from my Tree model) by Ancestry:

```
<%= @trees.arrange_serializable.to_json %>
```

That gives me nice JSON as follows (fragment only, apologies for the nonsense values):

```
[
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Milk",
    "note": "No details available",
    "created_at": "2014-09-20T13:22:03.262Z",
    "updated_at": "2014-09-20T13:48:46.301Z",
    "value": "3.06",
    "ancestry": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Farms",
            "note": "Some note here",
            "created_at": "2014-09-20T13:05:22.186Z",
            "updated_at": "2014-10-03T11:30:39.029Z",
            "value": "432.0",
            "ancestry": "2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "Zog",
                    "note": "Orc",
                    "created_at": "2014-09-27T22:11:20.874Z",
                    "updated_at": "2014-10-03T11:30:38.989Z",
                    "value": "11.0",
                    "ancestry": "2/1",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": 14,
                            "name": "Planes",
                            "note": "",
                            "created_at": "2014-10-04T01:01:12.890Z",
                            "updated_at": "2014-10-04T04:51:20.873Z",
                            "value": "422.0",
                            "ancestry": "2/1/8",
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

but the jstree plugin requires a particular format for the JSON as follows (from http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/):

```
{
  id          : "string" // will be autogenerated if omitted
  text        : "string" // node text
  icon        : "string" // string for custom
  state       : {
    opened    : boolean  // is the node open
    disabled  : boolean  // is the node disabled
    selected  : boolean  // is the node selected
  },
  children    : []  // array of strings or objects
  li_attr     : {}  // attributes for the generated LI node
  a_attr      : {}  // attributes for the generated A node
}
```

While the source hierarchical structure is perfect, I need to replace the attribute "name" in the original with "text" in the output, plus a few other changes.

At the back of my mind I feel there should be something elegant (like XSLT for XML) to translate JSON#1 into JSON#2 but I can't find any examples that do this.

Comment: Have you tried jbuilder? https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: No I haven't. It looks dandy but the big task is to get the tree structure out of Ancestry without having to write a recursive method to do so. It may be that I have to craft my own JSON instead of relying on the arrange_serializable method?

Comment: @karlingen jbuilder ended up working for me, thanks. But I've since realized that jstree (with its horrible documentation) wasn't exactly what I needed so I'm now rolling my own HTML in Rails.